# How to stop a TimeStamp from changing on every edits using Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I require some guidance regarding Google Apps Script, as I am a novice and facing some challenges while constructing a script. Presently, I have produced a script that registers the timestamp whenever there is an alteration in specific columns across two distinct tabs.
However, I am encountering an issue where the timestamp changes every time there is an edit in those cells. My objective is to create a script that captures the timestamp only on the initial edit and does not alter it subsequently.
Below, you can find my current script. I would greatly appreciate any assistance that can be extended.

```
function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if( s.getName() == "Production Activity" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
    if( r.getColumn() == 25 ) { //checks the column
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
      //if( nextCell.getValue() !== '' ) //is empty?
      nextCell.setValue(new Date());
    }

    if( r.getColumn() == 27 ) { //checks the column
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
      //if( nextCell.getValue() !== '' ) //is empty?
      nextCell.setValue(new Date());
    }
  }
  if( s.getName() == "Non-Production Activity" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
    if( r.getColumn() == 9 ) { //checks the column
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
      //if( nextCell.getValue() !== '' ) //is empty?
      nextCell.setValue(new Date());
    }

    if( r.getColumn() == 11 ) { //checks the column
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
      //if( nextCell.getValue() !== '' ) //is empty?
      nextCell.setValue(new Date());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The simple thing to do is not to write the timestamp if the cell is not blank

Comment: The script has if statements to check if the destination cell is empty, but they are commented out. Why has this been done? Have you commented out this lines or it was done by someone else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your situation and script, how about using `isBlank()` method of Class Range? When this is reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if (s.getName() == "Production Activity") { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
    if (r.getColumn() == 25) { //checks the column
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
      if (nextCell.isBlank()) {
        nextCell.setValue(new Date());
      }
    }

    if (r.getColumn() == 27) { //checks the column
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
      if (nextCell.isBlank()) {
        nextCell.setValue(new Date());
      }
    }
  }
  if (s.getName() == "Non-Production Activity") { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
    if (r.getColumn() == 9) { //checks the column
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
      if (nextCell.isBlank()) {
        nextCell.setValue(new Date());
      }
    }

    if (r.getColumn() == 11) { //checks the column
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
      if (nextCell.isBlank()) {
        nextCell.setValue(new Date());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

- When I saw your script and question, when the event object is used, I thought that the script might be simple. When this is reflected in the script, how about the following modified script?

  ```js
  function onEdit(e) {
    const obj = {
      "Production Activity": [25, 27],
      "Non-Production Activity": [9, 11]
    };
    const { range } = e;
    const o = obj[range.getSheet().getSheetName()];
    if (o && o.includes(range.columnStart)) {
      const dstRange = range.offset(0, 1);
      if (dstRange.isBlank()) {
        dstRange.setValue(new Date());
      }
    }
  }
  ```

#### References:

- [isBlank()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#isblank)
- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. The edit that you made to the original script, is working fine. But for the modified one that you suggested, I am getting an error that states

"Error TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'range' of 'e' as it is undefined.
onEdit @ Scrpt 1.gs:6"

Comment: @Somnath Banerjee About `Thank you for your quick response. The edit that you made to the original script, is working fine.`, welcome. Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: @Somnath Banerjee About `But for the modified one that you suggested, I am getting an error that states "Error TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'range' of 'e' as it is undefined. onEdit @ Scrpt 1.gs:6"`, in this case, I guess that you might directly run the function onEdit. In my 2nd proposed script, the event object `e` is not given. By this, such an error occurs. I deeply apologize for this error. `onEdit` is automatically run when the cell is edited. So, please edit the cell. By this, the same result with the above modified script is obtained.

Comment: @Somnath Banerjee Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.