# How to allow generation of Timestamp on protected cells using AppsScript for all non-sheet owners

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I hope this correspondence finds you well. I recently posted an [inquiry on TimeStamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77236932/how-to-stop-a-timestamp-from-changing-on-every-edits-using-apps-script) and was grateful to receive helpful feedback that aided me in resolving the matter. However, I have since encountered a new challenge.
My current task involves working on a spreadsheet that utilizes Appscript to capture Start and End times. With a script, I have implemented TimeStamp on edit. To ensure security, I have restricted access to certain columns by locking them, which limits access to specific individuals. Specifically, I have locked Columns 26 and 28 for Production Activity and Columns 10 and 12 for Non-production Activity.
Regrettably, I have encountered an issue where the timestamp does not generate for users who are restricted from editing the aforementioned columns. The timestamp only appears correctly when the cell protection is removed. Below is the current Apps Script

```
function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if (s.getName() == "Production Activity") { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
    if (r.getColumn() == 25) { //checks the column
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
      if (nextCell.isBlank()) {
        nextCell.setValue(new Date());
      }
    }

    if (r.getColumn() == 27) { //checks the column
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
      if (nextCell.isBlank()) {
        nextCell.setValue(new Date());
      }
    }
  }
  if (s.getName() == "Non-Production Activity") { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
    if (r.getColumn() == 9) { //checks the column
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
      if (nextCell.isBlank()) {
        nextCell.setValue(new Date());
      }
    }

    if (r.getColumn() == 11) { //checks the column
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
      if (nextCell.isBlank()) {
        nextCell.setValue(new Date());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As a result, I request your guidance on whether there is a feasible solution to generate the timestamp even when cell protection is enabled.

Thank you in advance for your valuable assistance.

Here is the [replica](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10E0juUbJkazLGce4Vq3xmQOUQiBEjH4oXObngDsNl8Q/edit?usp=sharing) of the original spreadsheet where I protected the above-mentioned columns for your reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- I think that the reason for your current issue of `Regrettably, I have encountered an issue where the timestamp does not generate for users who are restricted from editing the aforementioned columns. The timestamp only appears correctly when the cell protection is removed.` might be due to the simple trigger of OnEdit. In your situation, please use the installable OnEdit trigger.

When this is reflected in your script, please do the following flow.

#### 1. Rename function name

Please rename the function name from `onEdit` to `installedOnEdit`.

Because, when `onEdit` function is installed as the installable trigger of OnEdit, when a cell is edited, the function `onEdit` is executed 2 times with an asynchronous process. [Ref (Author: me)](https://tanaikech.github.io/2018/09/21/asynchronous-processing-using-event-triggers/)

#### 2. Install OnEdit trigger

**In this case, please operate the following install by the owner of Google Spreadsheet. The shared users are not required to do it. Please be careful about this.**

Please install the OnEdit trigger to `installedOnEdit`. You can see how to manually install OnEdit trigger at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#manage_triggers_manually

And, you can see the flow of installing it in the following image.

[image]

And also, the OnEdit trigger can be also installed by a script as follows.

```js
function installTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("InstalledonEdit").forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActive()).onEdit().create();
}
```

When you run this script, the OnEdit trigger is installed to the function `InstalledonEdit`. When I saw your Spreadsheet, it seemed that the function name was `InstalledonEdit`. So, I used it. Please be careful about this.

#### 3. Testing

Please edit a cell by a shared user who is not the owner of Spreadsheet. By this, the function `installedOnEdit` is automatically run by the installable trigger.

#### Note:

- From your showing script, when you don't want to use the event object, as another modification, how about the following modification? In this case, please install the OnEdit trigger to `installedOnEdit`, and edit a cell.

  ```js
  function installedOnEdit() {
    const obj = {
      "Production Activity": [25, 27],
      "Non-Production Activity": [9, 11],
    };
    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    const range = sheet.getActiveCell();
    const o = obj[sheet.getSheetName()];
    if (o && o.includes(range.getColumn())) {
      const dstRange = range.offset(0, 1);
      if (dstRange.isBlank()) {
        dstRange.setValue(new Date());
      }
    }
  }
  ```

  - If you can use the event object, I think that the script of https://stackoverflow.com/a/77237034 can be used by renaming the function name to `installedOnEdit`.

#### References:

- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

Comment: it is not working. After I changed OnEdt to installedOnEdit, the timestamp did not work even for me.

Comment: @Somnath Banerjee Thank you for replying. About `it is not working. After I changed OnEdt to installedOnEdit, the timestamp did not work even for me.`, I apologize for the inconvenience. Did you install the OnEdit trigger to the renamed function `installedOnEdit`? From your reply, I couldn't understand it. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill. When I tested my proposed flow, no error occurred and when a cell was edited, I confirmed that the script worked. I apologize for this situation.

Comment: @Somnath Banerjee You can see how to manually install OnEdit trigger at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#manage_triggers_manually

Comment: @Somnath Banerjee I updated my answer by including the method for installing the OnEdit trigger. Please confirm it.

Comment: thank you for the help and suggestions. I have implemented the same for one of my team and so far it is working fine so far. I will implement it for the whole after a day of observation. I have used the suggested script, which you have put up under the notes section, and it's working perfectly well. Thank you for the modified one and it's small and easy.

Comment: @Somnath Banerjee Welcome. Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: @Somnath Banerjee Thank you for your response. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.